# Voronoi game in discrete space

Tags: graphs, discrete-mathematics, game-theory, computer-games

Here i want to discuss about Linear Voronoi game. The game consists of two players, and a  finite set of users placed along a line. Each player has 2m facilities, where m>0 is a fixed integer. The game starts by the first player, placing 2 facilities on the line, followed by which  the second player places 2 facilities, and this continues for multiple rounds.  Assuming that each user is served by a facility closest to it, the payoff of each player is defined as the number of users  served by the facilities of that player. The goal of each player is to maximize his payoff. I am trying  to find an optimal strategies for last move of both players to find their best placements in the game.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?  Assuming you tried to solve it yourself and got stuck, it may be helpful if you wrote your thoughts and what you could not figure out. It will definitely draw more answers to your post.

Comment: Is [this paper](http://www.cs.ust.hk/~scheng/pub/vorgame.pdf) useful?  Also I see that [you have posted the same question elsewhere](http://www.scienceforums.net/topic/91302-linear-voronoi-game/), and in that post you gave a lot more context about what research you've done and what you found.  You should include what research you've done in the question.  [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and helps you get better answers.